# MSBuild Regex Value is empty

Tags: c#, .net, regex, msbuild

I can't get my regular expression to work in MSBuild (which is where i actually need it).

## Works correctly in C#:

```
        var input = @"Es wird versucht, das Paket aus ""Amusoft.EventManagement.csproj"" zu erstellen.;Paketerstellung der Dateien aus ""D:\SVN\Amusoft\Amusoft.EventManagement\Amusoft.EventManagement\bin\Release"".;""Amusoft.EventManagement.nuspec"" wird für Metadaten verwendet.;Das Paket ""D:\SVN\Amusoft\Amusoft.EventManagement\build\Amusoft.EventManagement\Release\WeakEvent.2.0.0.nupkg"" wurde erfolgreich erstellt.;Es wird versucht, das Symbolpaket für ""Amusoft.EventManagement.csproj"" zu erstellen.;Paketerstellung der Dateien aus ""D:\SVN\Amusoft\Amusoft.EventManagement\Amusoft.EventManagement\bin\Release"".;""Amusoft.EventManagement.nuspec"" wird für Metadaten verwendet.;Das Paket ""D:\SVN\Amusoft\Amusoft.EventManagement\build\Amusoft.EventManagement\Release\WeakEvent.2.0.0.symbols.nupkg"" wurde erfolgreich erstellt.";
        var m = Regex.Match(input, "(?<=\")[^\"]+nupkg(?=\")");
```

returns `D:\SVN\Amusoft\Amusoft.EventManagement\build\Amusoft.EventManagement\Release\WeakEvent.2.0.0.nupkg`

which is exactly what i want. However i can't get it to return anything in MSBuild, which is the place where i need it.

## MSBuild attempts to get it to work:

```
<Target Name="AfterBuild" Condition="'$(Configuration)' == 'Release'">
    <!-- Ensure Directory + Package project-->
    <MakeDir Directories="$(SolutionDir)build\$(ProjectName)\$(Configuration)\"/>
    <Exec ConsoleToMSBuild="true"  Command="nuget pack $(ProjectPath) -Symbols -Prop Configuration=Release -OutputDirectory $(SolutionDir)build\$(ProjectName)\$(Configuration)" >
        <Output TaskParameter="ConsoleOutput" ItemName="NugetPackOutput"/>
    </Exec>

    <!-- Prepare pushing process -->
    <Message Importance="High" Condition="!Exists('$(ProjectDir)nugetapikey.txt')" Text="nugetapikey.txt does not exist." />
    <ReadLinesFromFile Condition="Exists('$(ProjectDir)nugetapikey.txt')" File="$(ProjectDir)nugetapikey.txt">
        <Output TaskParameter="Lines" ItemName="NugetApiKey"/>
    </ReadLinesFromFile>
    <Message Importance="High" Condition="Exists('$(ProjectDir)nugetapikey.txt')" Text="NugetApiKey is '@(NugetApiKey)'" />
    <PropertyGroup>
        <NugetPackageFileName2>$([System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex]::Match(@(NugetPackOutput), `(?&lt;=&quot;)[^&quot;]+nupkg(?=&quot;)`))</NugetPackageFileName2>
        <NugetPackageFileName>$([System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex]::Match(@(NugetPackOutput), `(?&lt;=")[^"]+.nupkg(?=")`))</NugetPackageFileName>
        <NugetPushCommand>nuget push PICKNAMEINEXPLORER $(NugetPackageFileName) -ApiKey @(NugetApiKey) -Timeout 60 -Verbosity normal</NugetPushCommand>
    </PropertyGroup>
    <Message Importance="High" Text="Pushcommand is $(NugetPushCommand)" />
    <Message Importance="High" Text="Pack Output is @(NugetPackOutput)" />
    <Message Importance="High" Text="NugetPackageFileName is $(NugetPackageFileName)" />
    <Message Importance="High" Text="NugetPackageFileName2 is $(NugetPackageFileName2)" />
    <Message Importance="High" Text="Regex1 is $([System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex]::Match(@(NugetPackOutput), '.+'))" />
    <Message Importance="High" Text="Regex2 is $([System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex]::Match(@(NugetPackOutput), `.+`))" />
    <Message Importance="High" Text="Regex3 is $([System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex]::Match(@(NugetPackOutput), '(?&lt;=&quot;)[^&quot;]+nupkg(?=&quot;)'))" />
    <WriteLinesToFile Condition="Exists('$(ProjectDir)nugetapikey.txt')" File="$(SolutionDir)build\$(ProjectName)\$(Configuration)\pushcommand.txt" Lines="$(NugetPushCommand)" Overwrite="true"  Encoding="Unicode"/>
    <Exec ConsoleToMSBuild="true" ContinueOnError="true" IgnoreExitCode="true" Command="explorer.exe $(SolutionDir)build\$(ProjectName)\$(Configuration)" />
  </Target>
```

## Results of it:

`NugetPackageFileName is 
1>  NugetPackageFileName2 is 
1>  Regex1 is Es wird versucht, das Paket aus "Amusoft.EventManagement.csproj" zu erstellen.;Paketerstellung der Dateien aus "D:\SVN\Amusoft\Amusoft.EventManagement\Amusoft.EventManagement\bin\Release".;"Amusoft.EventManagement.nuspec" wird für Metadaten verwendet.;Das Paket "D:\SVN\Amusoft\Amusoft.EventManagement\build\Amusoft.EventManagement\Release\WeakEvent.2.0.0.nupkg" wurde erfolgreich erstellt.;Es wird versucht, das Symbolpaket für "Amusoft.EventManagement.csproj" zu erstellen.;Paketerstellung der Dateien aus "D:\SVN\Amusoft\Amusoft.EventManagement\Amusoft.EventManagement\bin\Release".;"Amusoft.EventManagement.nuspec" wird für Metadaten verwendet.;Das Paket "D:\SVN\Amusoft\Amusoft.EventManagement\build\Amusoft.EventManagement\Release\WeakEvent.2.0.0.symbols.nupkg" wurde erfolgreich erstellt.
1>  Regex2 is Es wird versucht, das Paket aus "Amusoft.EventManagement.csproj" zu erstellen.;Paketerstellung der Dateien aus "D:\SVN\Amusoft\Amusoft.EventManagement\Amusoft.EventManagement\bin\Release".;"Amusoft.EventManagement.nuspec" wird für Metadaten verwendet.;Das Paket "D:\SVN\Amusoft\Amusoft.EventManagement\build\Amusoft.EventManagement\Release\WeakEvent.2.0.0.nupkg" wurde erfolgreich erstellt.;Es wird versucht, das Symbolpaket für "Amusoft.EventManagement.csproj" zu erstellen.;Paketerstellung der Dateien aus "D:\SVN\Amusoft\Amusoft.EventManagement\Amusoft.EventManagement\bin\Release".;"Amusoft.EventManagement.nuspec" wird für Metadaten verwendet.;Das Paket "D:\SVN\Amusoft\Amusoft.EventManagement\build\Amusoft.EventManagement\Release\WeakEvent.2.0.0.symbols.nupkg" wurde erfolgreich erstellt.
1>  Regex3 is 
1>  Regex3 is`

`.+` and '.+' were attempts to verify whether inline Regex works at all - which is the case. However any actual attempt to get the value through regex fails.

Basically what i'm trying to do here is having a build script which (when i am done) will open a console window with a prefilled command to push the package to nuget, without dropping my apikey in source control/csproj. Apart from getting my Regex value the rest already worked in previous versions.

## Question:

Does anyone know what i'm doing wrong in the MSBuild version of the Regex?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is not with the regular expression. `Match` expects a `String` and it works well with `Properties`, but not with `Items`.

You need to change the type of your output for `Exec` (see below) and then refer to `$(NugetPackOutput)` instead of `@(NugetPackOutput)`.

**Before**

```
<Output TaskParameter="ConsoleOutput" ItemName="NugetPackOutput"/>
```

**After**

```
<Output TaskParameter="ConsoleOutput" PropertyName="NugetPackOutput"/>
```

Here is a test demonstrating this. Notice how in case of `MatchItem2`, the regular expression is actually matching the `ItemName` instead of the output.

**test.bat**

```
@ECHO off
ECHO Es wird versucht, das Paket aus "Amusoft.EventManagement.csproj" zu erstellen.;Paketerstellung der Dateien aus "D:\SVN\Amusoft\Amusoft.EventManagement\Amusoft.EventManagement\bin\Release".;"Amusoft.EventManagement.nuspec" wird für Metadaten verwendet.;Das Paket "D:\SVN\Amusoft\Amusoft.EventManagement\build\Amusoft.EventManagement\Release\WeakEvent.2.0.0.nupkg" wurde erfolgreich erstellt.;Es wird versucht, das Symbolpaket für "Amusoft.EventManagement.csproj" zu erstellen.;Paketerstellung der Dateien aus "D:\SVN\Amusoft\Amusoft.EventManagement\Amusoft.EventManagement\bin\Release".;"Amusoft.EventManagement.nuspec" wird für Metadaten verwendet.;Das Paket "D:\SVN\Amusoft\Amusoft.EventManagement\build\Amusoft.EventManagement\Release\WeakEvent.2.0.0.symbols.nupkg" wurde erfolgreich erstellt.
```

**BuildApp.csproj**

```
<Target Name="Test">
  <Exec ConsoleToMSBuild="true" Command="test.bat">
    <Output TaskParameter="ConsoleOutput" ItemName="OutputItem" />
    <Output TaskParameter="ConsoleOutput" PropertyName="OutputProperty" />
  </Exec>
  <Message Text="OutputItem: @(OutputItem)" />
  <Message Text="---" />
  <Message Text="OutputProperty: $(OutputProperty)" />
  <Message Text="---" />
  <Message Text="MatchItem1: $([System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex]::Match(@(OutputItem), '.+'))" />
  <Message Text="---" />
  <Message Text="MatchItem2: $([System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex]::Match(@(OutputItem), '.{5}'))" />
  <Message Text="---" />
  <Message Text="MatchItem3: $([System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex]::Match(@(OutputItem), '(?&lt;=&quot;)[^&quot;]+nupkg(?=&quot;)'))" />
  <Message Text="---" />
  <Message Text="MatchProperty: $([System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex]::Match($(OutputProperty), '(?&lt;=&quot;)[^&quot;]+nupkg(?=&quot;)'))" />
</Target>
```

**Test output**

```
Test:
  test.bat
  Es wird versucht, das Paket aus "Amusoft.EventManagement.csproj" zu erstellen
  .;Paketerstellung der Dateien aus "D:\SVN\Amusoft\Amusoft.EventManagement\Amu
  soft.EventManagement\bin\Release".;"Amusoft.EventManagement.nuspec" wird f?r
  Metadaten verwendet.;Das Paket "D:\SVN\Amusoft\Amusoft.EventManagement\build\
  Amusoft.EventManagement\Release\WeakEvent.2.0.0.nupkg" wurde erfolgreich erst
  ellt.;Es wird versucht, das Symbolpaket f?r "Amusoft.EventManagement.csproj"
  zu erstellen.;Paketerstellung der Dateien aus "D:\SVN\Amusoft\Amusoft.EventMa
  nagement\Amusoft.EventManagement\bin\Release".;"Amusoft.EventManagement.nuspe
  c" wird f?r Metadaten verwendet.;Das Paket "D:\SVN\Amusoft\Amusoft.EventManag
  ement\build\Amusoft.EventManagement\Release\WeakEvent.2.0.0.symbols.nupkg" wu
  rde erfolgreich erstellt.
  OutputItem: Es wird versucht, das Paket aus "Amusoft.EventManagement.csproj"
  zu erstellen.;Paketerstellung der Dateien aus "D:\SVN\Amusoft\Amusoft.EventMa
  nagement\Amusoft.EventManagement\bin\Release".;"Amusoft.EventManagement.nuspe
  c" wird f?r Metadaten verwendet.;Das Paket "D:\SVN\Amusoft\Amusoft.EventManag
  ement\build\Amusoft.EventManagement\Release\WeakEvent.2.0.0.nupkg" wurde erfo
  lgreich erstellt.;Es wird versucht, das Symbolpaket f?r "Amusoft.EventManagem
  ent.csproj" zu erstellen.;Paketerstellung der Dateien aus "D:\SVN\Amusoft\Amu
  soft.EventManagement\Amusoft.EventManagement\bin\Release".;"Amusoft.EventMana
  gement.nuspec" wird f?r Metadaten verwendet.;Das Paket "D:\SVN\Amusoft\Amusof
  t.EventManagement\build\Amusoft.EventManagement\Release\WeakEvent.2.0.0.symbo
  ls.nupkg" wurde erfolgreich erstellt.
  ---
  OutputProperty: Es wird versucht, das Paket aus "Amusoft.EventManagement.cspr
  oj" zu erstellen.;Paketerstellung der Dateien aus "D:\SVN\Amusoft\Amusoft.Eve
  ntManagement\Amusoft.EventManagement\bin\Release".;"Amusoft.EventManagement.n
  uspec" wird f?r Metadaten verwendet.;Das Paket "D:\SVN\Amusoft\Amusoft.EventM
  anagement\build\Amusoft.EventManagement\Release\WeakEvent.2.0.0.nupkg" wurde
  erfolgreich erstellt.;Es wird versucht, das Symbolpaket f?r "Amusoft.EventMan
  agement.csproj" zu erstellen.;Paketerstellung der Dateien aus "D:\SVN\Amusoft
  \Amusoft.EventManagement\Amusoft.EventManagement\bin\Release".;"Amusoft.Event
  Management.nuspec" wird f?r Metadaten verwendet.;Das Paket "D:\SVN\Amusoft\Am
  usoft.EventManagement\build\Amusoft.EventManagement\Release\WeakEvent.2.0.0.s
  ymbols.nupkg" wurde erfolgreich erstellt.
  ---
  MatchItem1: Es wird versucht, das Paket aus "Amusoft.EventManagement.csproj"
  zu erstellen.;Paketerstellung der Dateien aus "D:\SVN\Amusoft\Amusoft.EventMa
  nagement\Amusoft.EventManagement\bin\Release".;"Amusoft.EventManagement.nuspe
  c" wird f?r Metadaten verwendet.;Das Paket "D:\SVN\Amusoft\Amusoft.EventManag
  ement\build\Amusoft.EventManagement\Release\WeakEvent.2.0.0.nupkg" wurde erfo
  lgreich erstellt.;Es wird versucht, das Symbolpaket f?r "Amusoft.EventManagem
  ent.csproj" zu erstellen.;Paketerstellung der Dateien aus "D:\SVN\Amusoft\Amu
  soft.EventManagement\Amusoft.EventManagement\bin\Release".;"Amusoft.EventMana
  gement.nuspec" wird f?r Metadaten verwendet.;Das Paket "D:\SVN\Amusoft\Amusof
  t.EventManagement\build\Amusoft.EventManagement\Release\WeakEvent.2.0.0.symbo
  ls.nupkg" wurde erfolgreich erstellt.
  ---
  MatchItem2: @(Out
  ---
  MatchItem3:
  ---
  MatchProperty: D:\SVN\Amusoft\Amusoft.EventManagement\build\Amusoft.EventMana
  gement\Release\WeakEvent.2.0.0.nupkg
```

Comment: Interesting. At some point i've read a msbuild question suggesting to prefer item over property as output parameter. I didn't know it had such an impact. In hindsight with your explanation it does make sense though. Thank you!